# What's the correct way to pass a variable as an argument to another command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, read

For example I have this script that is meant to tweet from the shell, but I'm not sure I'm passing the variable correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "tweet>"
read tweet

curl -u user:pass -d status="$tweet" http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml
```

I'm not sure what is the correct way to do this in bash. I'm also curious if i can get the echo statement and the prompt for input to appear on the same line.

Comment: It depends upon the API, but your implementation is correct within the scope of the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct way for BASH scripting.

For input being on the same line, see [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720168/shell-script-read-on-same-line-after-echoing-a-message)

Try

```
read -p "tweet>" tweet
```